# Preventing user from going back in a browser window

Tags: javascript, back-button

Can someone please explain the working of this code ?

```
function preventBack(){window.history.forward();} 
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0); 
window.onunload=function(){null};
```

Comment: which part do you need help understanding?

Comment: As long as you don't want to actually want to prevent the user going back.

Comment: I want to know the flow when whole code executes

Answer (score 0):

```
window.history.forward();
```

The forward() method loads the next URL in the history list, which is same as clicking the "Forward button" in your browser. If you execute window.history.back(), then you will got to the previous page.

```
setTimeout(preventBack(), 0);
```

Here setTimeout function executes preventBack() function at every 0 milliseconds (so instantly). So, it will continuously keep executing the code by not giving the user any time to press the back button.

So, because of that the user won't be able to go back.

By the way, the name of function shouldn't be under double quotes.

```
window.onunload=function(){null};
```

This means the code inside the {} will be executed (which is null) before the user leaves the page.

Comment: what is the requirement of window.onload=function(){null};

Comment: If there is no code to execute then what is the use  ? If i remove "window.onuload" part  then the script dosen`t work. Also does setTimeout(preventBack(), 0); calls instantly or is executed only once ?

Comment: It will keep executing preventBack() infinite times (until you close the page). If you run setTimeout(preventBack(), 1000); then it will execute it every 1 second

Comment: If it executes infinitly then at every instant  if i return to that page(in which code is implemented)  from another page then i must be immediately forwarded automatically to the page from where i returned ? Dosent`t setInterval() do the same work ?

Comment: `setTimeout` only fires ONE time, after the specified time in milliseconds. `setInterval` fires multiple times, with at least the interval of specified time (can be much less, especially if the window/tab isn't active)

Comment: So why here setTimeout(preventBack(), 0); executes infinitly if "setTimeout" iexecutes only once